# Aggregate a column based on NAs in a different column

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to aggregate group2 based on NAs in group1:

```
Datetime            group1  group2
2011-08-08 21:00:00   1       1
2011-08-08 21:10:00   NA      2
2011-08-08 21:20:00   NA      3
2011-08-08 21:30:00   2       4
2011-08-08 21:40:00   NA      5
2011-08-08 21:50:00   NA      6
2011-08-08 22:00:00   3       7
```

This is my desired output:

```
Datetime            group1  group2
2011-08-08 21:00:00   1       1
2011-08-08 21:30:00   2       9 
2011-08-08 22:00:00   3       18
```

Edit:
9=2+3+4 and 18=5+6+7.

```
aggregate(group2~group1, data=Data, subset(Data,group1==NA),sum)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Can I do it with aggregate? or should I use different package?

Comment: @Richard, yes. But since the NA happens without any pattern I couldn't figure it out. Besides, I do not need code, just any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `na.locf` from package `zoo` would be quite useful here.

Assuming `dat` is your original data, we can take the dates for the non-NA `group1` levels and use `cbind` to bring them together with the aggregated `group2` data.

```
> library(zoo)
> Datetime <- dat$Datetime[!is.na(dat$group1)]
> cbind(Datetime, aggregate(group2~group1, na.locf(dat, fromLast = TRUE), sum))
#              Datetime group1 group2
# 1 2011-08-08 21:00:00      1      1
# 2 2011-08-08 21:30:00      2      9
# 3 2011-08-08 22:00:00      3     18
```

PS:  Thanks for updating/editing your question (+1).

Comment: Hi, I am following the lines above, and I am receiving the following error message. `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument`. `na.locf(dat, fromLast = TRUE)` is doing its job. But,`aggregate(group2~group1, na.locf(dat, fromLast = TRUE), sum)` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the `group1` and `group2` columns are class `numeric`.  Check `sapply(dat, class)`

Comment: I used akrun's dat below and created a data frame and made sure that group1 and group2 are numeric (previously they were integer). I also cleaned up R Console and restarted R. I somehow still receive the same error message. What could be a potential cause? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved it. `na.locf(dat, fromLast = TRUE)` made group1 and group2 character. So, `cbind(Datetime, aggregate(as.numeric(group2)~as.numeric(group1), na.locf(dat, fromLast = TRUE), sum))` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using base R:

```
ddf = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2011-08-08", class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(1:7, .Label = c("21:00:00", "21:10:00", 
    "21:20:00", "21:30:00", "21:40:00", "21:50:00", "22:00:00"
    ), class = "factor"), group1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
    3L), group2 = 1:7), .Names = c("Date", "time", "group1", 
"group2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

ddf$group1a = ddf$group1
for(i in nrow(ddf):1)   
     if(is.na(ddf$group1a[i])) 
          ddf$group1a[i] = ddf$group1a[i+1]
outdf = stack(with(ddf, tapply(group2, group1a, sum)))
names(outdf) = c("group2","group1")
outdf = outdf[,c(2,1)]
outdf

#  group1 group2
#1      1      1
#2      2      9
#3      3     18
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- DT[, group1:=cumsum(!is.na(c(0, group1[1:(.N-1)])))][,
       list(Datetime=Datetime[.N],group2=sum(group2)), by=group1][,c(2,1,3), with=FALSE]
  DT1
 #              Datetime group1 group2
 #1: 2011-08-08 21:00:00      1      1
 #2: 2011-08-08 21:30:00      2      9
 #3: 2011-08-08 22:00:00      3     18
```

#### data

```
 dat <- structure(list(Datetime = c("2011-08-08 21:00:00", "2011-08-08 21:10:00", 
 "2011-08-08 21:20:00", "2011-08-08 21:30:00", "2011-08-08 21:40:00", 
 "2011-08-08 21:50:00", "2011-08-08 22:00:00"), group1 = c(1L, 
 NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L), group2 = 1:7), .Names = c("Datetime", 
"group1", "group2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))
 DT <- data.table(dat)
```